# Route all outgoing http requests to a kind of proxy server

Tags: linux, http, proxy, routes

I would like to route all outgoing HTTP requests from a Linux machine to a remote system where I can process the requests. How can I achieve this in Linux? I just want to route HTTP requests. Not all web traffic. Thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out @hells?

Answer (score 0):

You can use iptables for instance. However, you need to identify how the desired HTTP requests will be distinguished from the other "WEB traffic" you have mentioned. As first idea you can use port number or IP address of your destination host (as well as your source host).

OR (depends on your SW), you can teach your tools whose HTTP requests should be rerouted how to use proxy.

And the last option I know, will require you to write some kernel module for ip filter which can look inside your packages and do the routing.

UPDATED: ah yes, you can also substitute relevant domain name in /etc/hosts or by other means to let your client transparently connect to your desired IP address instead of the real one as per HTTP request. But here you should keep in mind if your web client will have redirections or links to another hostnames, you also need to substitute them or requests to them will go directly and you don't catch them.